# How to read a cookies value with jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, cookies

I have a cookie named "Name" with a value = "data".

My cookie looks like this:

```
var result = $.cookie("Name");

result = "value = data"
```

but all i need is the "data". not "value=data"

i haven't found anyway in JavaScript that's similar to C# where i can just do

```
var result = Request.Cookies["Name"]["value"];
```

There should be a JavaScript method like:

```
var result = $.cookie("Name").("value");
```

**MORE INFO**

I'm setting the cookie initially this way in C# not sure if this is proper?

```
 var httpCookie = Response.Cookies["Name"];
            if (httpCookie != null)
            {
                httpCookie["value"] = "data";
            }

when trying to set httpCookie = "data" //Error: Cannot convert source type 'string; to target type 'System.Web.HttpCookie'
```

Comment: how are you setting the cookie? it shouldn't contain the value "value = data".

Comment: A cookie just holds a string, not an object, so you can't subscript it.

Comment: see my MORE INFO update

Comment: yeah, that's not right. you shouldn't be adding a value property to it. but... i'm not familiar with C# so i'm not really sure, just basing this off of the outcome.

Comment: when i try to put httpCookie = "data" i says "Cannot convert source type 'string; to target type 'System.Web.HttpCookie'"

Comment: No idea, never worked with C#. Research setting http cookies in C#.

Comment: Are you using this extension: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie? There is no `$.cookie()` function in jQuery alone. If you are using this plugin, the documentation on the linked page above shows `$.cookie('name', 'value')` as the correct syntax. Setting `$.cookie.json = true;` allows for the stringifying and parsing of objects stored as cookies...

Comment: isn't he *getting* a cookie value clientside, not setting? he's getting he value correctly currently, the value just don't contain the expected value...

Comment: @KevinB Possibly. It seems a little unclear. If so, then setting `$.cookie.json = true; var result = $.cookie("name"); console.log(result.value);` will return the OP the correct value if the C# code is saving the object as a cookie correctly. Judging by the fact that the OP is receiving the C# error, I doubt that is the correct implementation for setting the cookie and I also doubt that the cookie really needs to be returned as a parsable object as oppose to the value. Code be wrong but to me all signs point to an incorrect C# cookie implementation though I'm not familiar enough to say where.

Comment: This link may be able to help you with understanding how to implement the cookie code in C# .NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1.

Comment: @War10ck - Yeah when setting $.cookie.json = true; $.cookie("name") is always undefined. I will do a bit more research on implementing. I guess i can always just pull the string and str.replace("value=", ""); which is highly inadequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so the answer was clear.

to set a cookie value in C# its done as:

```
httpCookie.Value = "data";
```

i was incorrect setting it as:

```
httpCookie["Value"] = "data";
```